# Consume DirectExchange messages using routing key and exchange in spring boot

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Am trying to consume the message from *exiting queue* which is of type **Direct Exchange**(created with the help of exchange and routing key). I have only the **exchange name** and **routing key** and **not the queue name**. There were support for plain Java, but there was no place where I can find it for Spring boot.

```
@RabbitListener
    @RabbitHandler
    public void consumeMessage(Object message) {
        LOGGER.debug("Message Consumed.... : {}", message.toString());
    }
```

How can I consume messages  with routing key and exchange name not the queue  name as `@RabbitListener` asks for `queue`.

Comment: With a direct exchange, the routing key is the queue name.

Comment: @theMayer ```@RabbitListener(queues = "${routing.key}")
 @RabbitHandler
 public void consumeMessage(Object message) {
  LOGGER.debug("Message Consumed.... : {}", message.toString());
 }``` This is giving a exception 404 - `reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue`

Comment: Have you declared the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers consume from queues not exchanges. You must bind a queue to the exchange with the routing key.

**EDIT**

There are several ways to automatically declare a queue on the broker.

```java
    @RabbitListener(bindings = 
        @QueueBinding(exchange = @Exchange("myExchange"), 
            key = "myRk", value = @Queue("")))
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
```

This will bind an anonymous queue (auto-delete) which will be deleted when the application is stopped.

```java
    @RabbitListener(bindings = 
        @QueueBinding(exchange = @Exchange("myExchange"), 
            key = "myRk", value = @Queue("foo")))
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
```

Will bind a permanent queue `foo` to the exchange with the routing key.

You can also simply declare `#Bean` s for the queue, exchange and binding.

See [Configuring the broker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#broker-configuration).

Comment: I was supplied only with the Exchange Name and Routing Key not the queue name.

Comment: So you need to bind a queue to that exchange with the routing key and then consume from that queue.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russel.
One more question - Do we have any provision to keep on retrying for a RMQ connection if there were any interruption in the connnection or channel?

Comment: You should really ask a new question each time - new questions in comments don't help people to find answers. On the consumer sider, the listener container will attempt to reconnect every 5 seconds (by default). On the producer side you can add a suitably configured `RetryTemplate` to the `RabbitTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks and it works.... :) From next time I will post it as a question. @gary-russell